# Delete row from table using Ajax and ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC with a repository pattern

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Ajax to delete data from table. On clicking the delete button, I want status of that row to be set to False. Code is working perfectly on the server side. I have checked delete API on Swagger and it is working fine. It is not working from the frontend only.

Here's the code:

PublicationRepository.cs

```
public void DeletePublication(int id)
{
    var publication = _context.publications.Find(id);

    if (publication != null)
    {
        publication.Status = false;
        _context.publications.Update(publication);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

PublicationController:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("DeletePublication")]
public void DeletePublication(int id)
{
    iPublications.DeletePublication(id);
}
```

index.cshtml

```
<button  class='btn  btn-info btnDelete' id='btnDelete"+ obj.id + "'>Delete</button>

$(document).on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
    var publicationId = $(this).attr('id');
    publicationId = publicationId.replace("btnDelete", "");
    alert(publicationId);
       if (confirm("It will be deleted permanently. Are you sure?")) {
           var obj = { "id": publicationId };
          
           $.ajax({
               url: '/api/Publication/DeletePublication?id' +publicationId,
               type: "DELETE",
               contentType: 'application/json',
               dataType: "json",
               data: JSON.stringify(obj),
               success: function(data) {

                $('#btnDelete' + obj.id).closest('tr').remove();
                        $('.tdSrNo').each(function (index,obj) {
                            $(this).html(index+1);
                        });
                        alert("Deleted successfully");
               }
           });
       }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean after you access the delete endpoint, The frontend will not remove this row from the page?

Answer (score 0):

In the action of your backend, The return type of `DeletePublication` is void, So it will not return anything, You should not specify the `dataType`  in ajax or it will report `Unexpected end of JSON input` in error function. From your code, you want to send data in URL, So it's no need to add:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
```

Here is a simple working demo based on your code, Hope it can help you solve this issue:

```
@model List<TestModel>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for(int i=0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model[i].Name</td>
                <td>@Model[i].Age</td>
                <td><button class='btn  btn-info btnDelete' id="btnDelte_@i">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    @section Scripts{
        <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.btnDelete', function () {
            var publicationId = $(this).attr('id');
            newpublicationId = publicationId.substring(9);
            //alert(newpublicationId);
            if (confirm("It will be deleted permanently. Are you sure?")) {
                var obj = { "id": newpublicationId };

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:7273/api/Test?id=' + newpublicationId,
                    type: "DELETE",
                    success: function (data) {
                        
                        document.getElementById(publicationId).closest('tr').remove();
                        //$('.tdSrNo').each(function (index, obj) {
                        //    $(this).html(index + 1);
                        //});
                        alert("Deleted Successfully");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert("Error occurred: " + error);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
        </script>
    }
```

Gif Demo

[image]

Comment: @musfirah hamid, Have you solved the issue now?